# Is it possible to auto mount OSx Extended File system partitioned drive on raspbian Jessie with write permission?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, hard-drive, filesystem

I have OSx Extended formatted hard disk which I want to mount on Raspbian Jessie,

I am following this in `/etc/fstab`

`# New OSx Journel File System 160 GB HDD added on Sun Sept 25 - 14:28 IST 2016`
`UUID=f975bce7-5854-3e02-b3cd-d283239f952f /home/pi/mercury/ hfs defaults,users,noatime,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,rw,umask=0000 0 2`

but it is not auto mounting !

Comment: Stuff in `/etc/fstab` is only potentially automounted *at boot*.  After that it is just used to determine default settings for a particular device.  I think post-boot automounting on Raspbian is managed via PCmanFM, the [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) file browser, so if you don't have that GUI running, you'll have to make other arrangements.  You should just try `mount`ing it manually to make sure it works at all.

Comment: but the other NTFS partitioned drive mounts from `/etc/fstab` just fine on boot. this `hfsplus` doesnt

Comment: At a glance I'd say what you have there should mean it is automounted at boot.  My point was that's all it applies to, boot.  If you plug it in subsequently it won't just because of that.  Also, I'm not sure about all the subtleties in that configuration.  Again: **You need to check if you can mount it manually**.  If you cannot, then there is no way it is going to automount.

Comment: Have you got the HFS+ driver installed? ```sudo apt-get install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is imprecise. Can you `mount` manually or not at all, or is the question abnout `rw`? I guess the drive doesn't mount at all.

I mount regularly using `hfsplus` e.g `UUID=8ee3d7d1-354c-30b4-8259-d8a387f422a1       /mnt/XXXX     hfsplus    ro,noauto,relatime,umask=22,uid=1000,gid=1000,nls=utf8  0     0` but then I don't want ANY drives to automount and I NEVER mount HFS drives as RW because Linux does not support journalling.